# Is there anything like bootstrap for android?

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in Android programming (with Java) I have lots of problem with styling my page. with wide tablets and small mobiles and etc... .

Is there anything (library) like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (That is for styling on web) to working with it?

Comment: I'm old enough in Android development. I have a lot of problems with styling/themes and different devices support. Try to read Google's specification regarding Material Design and implement all these styles yourself http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of articles online about using Bootstrap and Font Awesome when developing Android apps (html & JavaScript apps that is)

http://java.dzone.com/articles/now-you-can-get-bootstrap

Depending on your development work flow you can use Twitter Bootstrap and phonegap to convert it into a native android app.